# Is it possible to get events from the GitHub API by event id?

Tags: javascript, github-api

The documentation says that I can get events for a particular user or repo, but is there any way to retrieve github events by an event id only?

Comment: What are you trying to do? As far as I'm aware there is no general event API, but you can get a list of all public repositories and then list their events—I suspect you'll burn through your rate limit very quickly if you can keep up with the event stream at all...

Comment: I'm working on a web app that works with trello and with githbub api. With trello Api I can retrieve any action by its id. Would be great to have such functionality using github Api.